# Error: The value you selected is not a valid choice

Tags: php, symfony

Currently, I am updating the system running on the existing Symfony 2.3 (currently 3.0.9), and I am verifying the operation.
　I want to save the data selected in Form in the DB, but some data that uses ChoiceType cannot be saved due to `The value you selected is not a valid choice.`

It seems that the data passed is the same as the system before the update to the DB, but it seems to be rejected.

One thing that seems to be related to the error is that I replaced the numbers and words in the parameters in services.yml.

This is because what was displayed on the page was a number, although the word was supposed to be displayed.
Could you give me some advice?

**Error**

```
shop_keepRequestMinRank => The value you selected is not a valid choice.
shop_prefId => The value you selected is not a valid choice.
```

**Code**
ShopController.php

```
if ($request-> isMethod('PUT')){
    if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()){
        // save save
        $this->get("admin.shopService")->save($shop);
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success','Saved shop profile.');
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl ('ahi_sp_admin_shop_shop_edit'));
        } else {
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error','Could not save shop profile. Please check your entries.');
        }
    }
}
```

Services.yml

```
parameters:
#member rank
   amc_member_rank:
       "White": 0
       "Navy": 1
       "Orange": 2
       "Silver": 3
       "Black": 4

   prefectures:
       "Hokkaido": 1
       "Aomiriken": 2
```

Parameters.php

```
/ **
      * Get the prefecture's
      *
      * @return array Prefectures
      * /
     public static function getPrefectures()
     {
         return self::$container->getParameter("prefectures");
     }
      / **
      * Get the key of the prefecture
      *
      * @return array Prefectural key
      * /
     public static function getPrefecturesKeys ()
     {
         return array_keys(self::getPrefectures());
     }
/ **
      * Get AMC membership rank
      *
      * @return array AMC member rank
      * /
     public static function getAmcMemberRank()
     {
         return self::$container->getParameter("amc_member_rank");
     }

     / **
      * Get a key for membership rank
      *
      * @return array member rank key
      * /
     public static function getAmcMemberRankKeys()
     {
         return array_keys(self::getAmcMemberRank());
     }
```

ShopType.php

```
// Prefectures
$builder->add("prefId", ChoiceType::class, array(
    "required"=>true,
    "choices"=>Parameters::getParameter("prefectures"),
));

// The lowest rank that can be reserved
$builder->add("keepRequestMinRank", ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices'=>Parameters::getParameter('amc_member_rank'),
    'expanded'=>false,
    'required'=>true,
));
```

**Version**
Cent OS 6.7 PHP 5.6 Symfony3.0.9

Comment: The posted code has some syntax errors. When writing variables, you can't have a space after the `$` and the variable name. Example: `->save($ shop)` should be `->save($shop)` and `$ builder` should be `$builder`. Those should throw parse/syntax errors.

Comment: @MerrinK - When suggesting an edit, do _not_ change the original code. It's Ok to format the code to be more readable, but do not change the actual code (like adding missing `}`).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you for pointing out. I fixed the code. There was a space when I copied and pasted it. There are no spaces in the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 2.7 they added choices_as_values option, as the data supplied to a ChoiceType is now reversed (keys with values)

For backward compatibility you must set choices_as_values to false.
For the long run you must reverse all your data arrays for ChoiceType values.

See https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices-as-values

Extra advice: When upgrading major versions read the UPGRADE.md file from the new version and check for Breaking Changes (BC). Moreover, you should have first upgraded to symfony 2.8 as that is a version special made for transitioning from symfony 2 to 3, and firstly fix all the deprecation warnings.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
Originally, Choices_as_values is not used, and the key and value of services.yml are replaced at the timing of updating to 3.0, so I think that it is not related to this error, but how about it?
>Extra advice: 
You're right. I updated it to 2.8 once, but now I'm suffering because I have checked the operation in detail.